# Wordpress 3 plugin to control widget visibility

Tags: wordpress, joomla, widget, visibility

Coming from a Joomla background one of the fist things I realised is that Wordpress 3 doesn't have native support for controlling the visibility of widgets (modules in Joomla).

I've tried:

- Dynamic widgets - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-widgets/screenshots/ but it seems to break the admin menus.
- Also tried Widget context - but it doesn't display correctly and doesn't allow granularity on the page visibility level.

Can anybody recommend a solution?

Comment: Do you want for example to display a text only for admins or editors (level)?

Comment: That would be useful. But what I really need is the ability to set a widget to display on page-a but not display on page-b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Widget Logic -- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/

Hope this helps!

-æ.

Comment: Thanks, it does work, (I'm using it for now) but I'm looking for a user friendly functionality that an inexperienced user wouldn't have a problem with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Display Widgets](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/display-widgets/). It adds checkboxes to each widget to either show or hide it on every site page: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/display-widgets/screenshots/

Make sure to disable other similar plugins to avoid conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Example from sidebar.php:

```
<div class="sidebar-box border-radius-6px">
    <h2>Dream Categories</h2>
    <ul>
        <?php wp_list_categories('title_li='); ?>
    </ul>
</div><!-- Sidebar Box End -->
```

Lets say you want to display this only on a page called "about-us". use is_page() function provided by wordpress.

```
<?php if(is_page('about-us')) { ?>
<div class="sidebar-box border-radius-6px">
        <h2>Dream Categories</h2>
        <ul>
            <?php wp_list_categories('title_li='); ?>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- Sidebar Box End -->
<?php } ?>
```

And as for the user level:

```
<?php if(current_user_can('level_10')) { // Level 10 = Administrator ?> 
<div class="sidebar-box border-radius-6px">
    <h2>Dream Categories</h2>
        <ul>
            <?php wp_list_categories('title_li='); ?>
        </ul>
</div><!-- Sidebar Box End -->
<?php } ?>
```

Please see [Wordpress User Levels](http://codex.wordpress.org/User_Levels)

PS: I saw the plugin provided by **aendrew** and I had a look at it.
Try this:
Make a backup of widget_login.php file then open it, search for **line 75** and replace it with **update_option("widget_logic", "is_page('" . $wl_options . "')");** This should easy up the stuff a little, when you limit a widget you have to add **is_page('bla-bla')** in that input that line should only require **bla-bla** (If the page is called Bla Bla) [not tested, but you can give it a try.]

Comment: Hi, thans for your suggestions. The most important thing is that I want the visibility of a widget to be controlled through the CMS, so it can be altered by any admin user.

Comment: I tried updating widget_login.php, but it prevents the widget logic data from being saved properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/conditional-widgets/

Really user friendly, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for a plugin for this purpose, check out my plugin [Widget Visibility](http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-visibility/).

It's user friendly (uses checkboxes) and works inside the [WordPress customizer](http://s.w.org/plugins/widget-visibility/screenshot-2.jpg) too.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the place to promote add-ins. It's preferred not to post if only to recommend one..

Comment: @BernardSaucier - So how should I answer the question if it is asking for a plugin recommendation? I had the same issue with OP so I made this plugin and I am hoping it would help others as well.

Comment: Generally the same goes for questions; guess this one fell off the radar.